# Clarification on proof: Order of left cosets equal

Tags: abstract-algebra

There is a lemma that says that all left cosets $aH$ of a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ have the same order.

The proof given is as follows...

The multiplication by $a \in G$ defines the map $H \rightarrow aH$ that sends $h\mapsto ah$. This map is bijective because its inverse is multiplication by $a^{-1}$.

I don't quite understand the proof. Why does having a bijective map mean that all sets of left cosets have the same order?
Thank you

Comment: The order of a coset is defined as its cardinality. Two sets have the same cardinality if and only if there is a bijection between them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because this is the definition of having the same cardinality.

Comment: I understand that $H$ and $aH$ will have the same cardinality, but if there was another element $b \in G$ such that there was another coset $bH = {bh \mid h \in H}$, then what says that the cardinalities of $aH$ and $bH$ are the same?

Comment: Never mind, understood. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

First, you should know that two sets $A,B$ have the same size (by
definition) if there is a bijection $f:A\to B$ (in this case there
is also a bijection $g:B\to A$).

You can understand why this is the definition in the case that $A,B$
are finite by using a drawing.

Second, $|aH|=|H|=|bH|$ (since the size of every coset is equal to
the size of $H$) and thus all cosets have the same cardinality.

Comment: Thank you, your second point is something I just realized (embarrassingly slowly I might add)

Comment: @achacttn - happens to everyone!